# RDLC Page Footer not displaying visual studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, export-to-excel, rdlc

I have a project in which I have to use Visual Studio 2008, and I'm trying feverishly to add a Page Footer.  It adds from the top menu in VS 2008 under "Reports"

However, I cannot see it getting displayed.  I have a Excel export link that rips through all the code rendering out the RDLC into Excel.

I added a company logo image to the top as a Page Header, that works fine, but not sure why zero from text/images/static and dynamic text is not appearing in footer / bottom of excel page from the RDLC.

Anyone?

Comment: Are you sure to have the right view in Excel? In Excel 2010 View -> Page Layout. [Reference](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/use-page-layout-view-to-fine-tune-pages-before-printing-HA010021563.aspx#BMhideheadersfootersmargins)

Comment: No, This is done in Visual Studio in the RDLC file.  You simply cannot be in Excel doing this.

Comment: I am having a similar issue... data will populate with Report Variables in the Header, but in the Footer, the variables are not pulled in.  This is only for Excel, PDF render will pull the values in.

Comment: It has been 3 years since I wrote that... I haven't done any RDLC in a long time.   Actually I recall using a 3rd party open source tool  NPOI to help with various tasks that vs 2008 with being prior to .net 4.0  the limitations    ...     so I recall using this    https://npoi.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

Wow, spent a lot of time on this. Finally figured out after looking at the spreadsheet in print preview mode that the footers are in fact there, they just don't show up in the rows.

Comment: @Xeuron - It's not my question :)